Merging PISA 2000 student file with ESCS index file
I am using PISA data from 2000, 2003 & 2018. I am using the ESCS index. For 2000, the ESCS index is not included in the student file and has to be merged with the student file. However, I load both datasets in R, the ESCS file has more than double the observations. How do I merge these files?
First, I made a subset of the PISA 2000 student file and kept the variables that I need.
Then I tried to merge this file with the ESCS file.
setwd("~/Desktop/Competition")
library(haven)
pisa <- read_sav("PISA2000.sav") 
SES <- read_sav("ESCS_PISA2000.sav") 

# Maths achievement (Y)
pv1math

# Competitive learning (M)
tibble(pisa$comlrn)

# SES index (Z)
ESCS

# Controls
# SEX
ST03Q01

# Grade
pisa$ST02Q01

# Immigrant status

# Country of birth student
tibble(pisa$ST16Q01)
# Country of birth father 
tibble(pisa$ST16Q03)
# Country of birth mother
tibble(pisa$ST16Q02)

#Creating a variable with 3 levels: native, first gen, and     second gen
pisa$immigrant <- NA
pisa$immigrant[pisa$ST16Q01 == 1] <- 1
pisa$immigrant[pisa$ST16Q01 == 1 & pisa$ST16Q02 == 2 |         pisa$ST16Q03 == 2] <-2
pisa$immigrant[pisa$ST16Q01 == 2] <-3 

# Subset to smaller dataset 
subset <- pisa[, c("STIDSTD", "pv1math", "comlrn", "COUNTRY",     "ST03Q01", "ST02Q01","immigrant", "SCHOOLID", "SUBNATIO")]

data <-merge(subset, SES, by=c("STIDSTD", "SCHOOLID",     "SUBNATIO"), all = T)


                     


Welcome to SO. Can you provide a reproducible example for the input data. Are you using any external packages?

Hi! I only use the haven package to load the .sav files but no other packages.

This question is similar to: How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Including a reproducible sample from your dataset would help here. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example
